# How do I check if a space is in a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to coding and my first project is a hangman game. I am trying to make it so that when there is a space in a input that it will tell the user that the input is invalid.

I am using a or statement to check if there is a "" or " " in the input. When I input anything though, regardless if it meets the requirements, It will not take the input and when I click enter it just gives me a new line as if it is not recognizing the input.

```
Player1 = str(input("It's Player 1's turn> ").lower())
            while Player1 == "" or " " in Player1:
                if Player1 == "":
                    Player1 = input("Please enter a letter to continue> ")
                    continue
                elif Player1 in word:
                    for match in re.finditer(Player1, word):
                        start = (match.start())
                        end = (match.end())
                        HiddenWord = HiddenWord[:start] + Player1 + HiddenWord[end:]
                    guess_1 = True
                else:
                    guess_1 = False
```

when I click enter with any input, it will just move me to a new line and not recognize it

Comment: It's probably better that you check for valid input, rather than the opposite.

Comment: You already have the right condition for the `while` statement to look for a space in the input. Just use the same condition for the `if` statement.